# How to add only those records which are not already added to database

Tags: python, postgresql

I'm using Postgresql. I have code as follows:

```
vehicles = get_vehicle_references()
for vehicle in vehicles:
    insert_into_db(vehicle[0], vehicle[1])
```

And `get_vehicle_references()` is as follows:

```
def get_vehicle_references():
    conn = db_connection()
    cur = conn.cursor()
    try:
        s = "SELECT reference, reference_url FROM vehicles v WHERE NOT EXISTS (select reference from daily_run_vehicle rv WHERE handled = %s AND retries < %s  AND rv.timestamp::timestamp::date = %s AND v.reference=reference) ORDER BY id DESC"
        cur.execute(s, (False, 5, today))
        return cur.fetchall()
    except Exception as e:
        capture_error(str(e))
    conn.close()
```

Thus the query in that function is as follows:

```
SELECT reference, reference_url
FROM vehicles v
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (select reference from daily_run_vehicle rv
     WHERE handled = False
         AND retries < 5
         AND rv.timestamp::timestamp::date = str(date.today())
         AND v.reference=reference)
ORDER BY id DESC
```

I get the `reference` and the `reference_url` and then I insert them in the database.

I repeat this more than 500 times every day. What I want is as follows:

- When it executes the first time, if the `reference` from `vehicles` in `daily_run_vehicle` has `handled` field = `False` and `retries < 5`, I want to insert that `reference` in database.
- When it goes to that query again that same day, I want to check if that
  `reference` in `daily_run_vehicle` has `handled` field = `False` and `retries < 5` has already been added to `daily_run_vehicle` table that day.
  If its already been added I want to skip that record.

I'm lost here. Can anybody help me please.

Answer (score 3):

Add a [UNIQUE INDEX](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/indexes-unique.html) to the table you are inserting records into:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX yourtable_idx on yourtable (date, reference, reference_url);
```

Notice that the `date` is part of the unique index. So each unique `(date, reference, reference_url)` tuple can only be inserted once.

Then you can insert records into `yourtable` using the SQL:

```
INSERT INTO table (date, reference, reference_url)
VALUES (%s, %s, %s)
ON CONFLICT (date, reference, reference_url) DO NOTHING
```

The [`ON CONFLICT ... DO NOTHING`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT) clause tells Postgresql to ignore the insert if the 
`(date, reference, reference_url)` tuple is already in `yourtable`.

Once you've set up your Postgresql table with a unique index, you can insert with impunity and not have to worry about creating duplicates in your Python code. It's much easier and more reliable to enforce this at the database level than it is to code this consistently at the application level.